# I need help manipulating my code so it matches the desired output. Attached is my code, desired output, my output, and the txt file

Tags: python, function, output

Here is my code which runs, but the format of the output is slightly different than what is required:

```py
def main():

    feet = populateDictionary("Units.txt")
    displayUnits(feet)
    orig, dest, length = getInput()
    ans = length * feet[orig] / feet[dest]
    print("Length in {0}: {1:,.4f}".format(dest, ans))

def populateDictionary(fileName):
    infile = open(fileName, 'r')
    feet = {}
    for line in infile:
        temp = line.split(',')
        feet[temp[0]] = eval(temp[1])
    return feet

def displayUnits(feet):
    print("UNITS OF LENGTH")
    i = 0
    for key in feet:
        print((key + '\t').expandtabs(12), end="")
        i += 1
        if i % 3 == 0:
            print()
    print()
    
def getInput():
    orig = input("Units to convert from: ")
    dest = input("Units to convert to: ")
    length = eval(input("Enter length in " + orig + ": "))
    return orig, dest, length


main()
```

Here is a copy of my output, the issue relates to how the UNITS OF LENGTH are shown. They should match exactly to the image containing the desired output:
[image]

This is the desired output, I need help manipulating my code so it formats UNITS OF LENGTH exactly as the desired output:

[image]

[Units.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSXYU.png):

```
inches,.083333
furlongs,660
yards,3
fathoms,6
feet,1
kilometers,3281.5
meters,3.2815
miles,5280
rods,16.5
```

Comment: The question title should describe the specific problem.

Comment: Don't use `eval()`. Use either `int()` or `float()` to parse numbers.

Comment: is there some logic to the order of the units? It doesn't seem to be alphabetical.

Comment: The example output says "possible outcome"; to me that means that this is not a strict output that you absolutely must adhere to, in terms of the order of the units being displayed. Are you certain that the order, which has no functional effect on the program, has to be exactly laid out like in the example? I suppose you could, instead of looping through the unit names in order, specify the order by using a list of indices, like `[0, 1, 2, 8, 7, 3, 6, 5, 4]`, and explicitly getting the key at each of those indices.

Comment: Never ever again use `eval` until you've read and fully understood the information at [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Yes, the task asked for output to be identical to that of the desired output. It doesn't make much sense why it would matter, but those were the instructions. I will make the necessary changes, but any other input would be helpful.